# Ubuntu Gnome shortcuts triggered on-press and not on-release

Tags: shortcut-keys, ubuntu-gnome

I've noticed that on my Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS all ubuntu shortcuts are triggered on-press instead of on-release. This makes using them with other programs pretty annoying e.g. I'm using two layouts for the keyboard, so I can switch between them with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>. In Eclipse however I would like to use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to open Run menu. With current configuration of Ubuntu, the moment I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> in Eclipse, I automatically switch keyboard layout.

Is it possible to switch this behavior somehow? Or do I need to remap the shortcuts so there would be no conflicts?

Comment: It is known bug - see [launchpad bug 1245473](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1245473).