# Ubuntu 17.10 GNOME ctrl + shift + v in terminal triggers language change

Tags: shortcut-keys, 17.10, keyboard-layout, gnome-shell

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to change keyboard layout and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> in terminal.
It never was a problem with Unity but now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> immediately changes language so that I can't use it for other shortcuts. Is there a way to solve this for GNOME without changing those shortcuts?

Comment: This has already been asked before [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/857773/ubuntu-gnome-shortcuts-triggered-on-press-and-not-on-release) & [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784864/ctrlshift-also-changes-language-when-just-ctrlshift-should-do-it). Looks like there isn't any other solution, see this [bug report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865) for details. Best option is to reset those shortcuts and use system defaults, e.g. <super>space, <shift><super>space for layout switching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is known ugly bug - see [launchpad bug 1245473](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1245473).

I'm writing this from Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with MATE DE. It does not have this problem.
I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> layout switcher for English and Russian languages.
I see no interference here.

But MATE on Ubuntu 17.10 has this problem - see other [launchpad bug 1720364](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1720364).

My complete position is written [in comment 528 for bug 1218322 at launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322/comments/528).

Comment: I use MATE 17.10 and right ctrl + right shift for input language switch - that stays out of my way because I used left ctrl and left shift as mod keys. MATE provides a lot of options for language switch shortcuts (I realise this may not be at all helpful to you, just wanted to mention in case it's of interest to others)