# Ubuntu 17.10 - Combination of CTRL + SHIFT is handled the wrong way

Tags: 17.10, keyboard-layout

I have 2 languages installed, normally I switch between them using CTRL + SHIF combination of keys. I updated few months ago Ubuntu to 17.10 and now I can't work in my IDE or other programs where I use CTRL + SHIFT + [SOME_KEY], because in 17.10 handles it the wrong way.
Where as previously (in 17.04), I didn't have such problems. So, basically in the programs I can't use CTRL + SHIFT + F for example, it just switches the languages.

P.S. Please, don't propose the solution to change the combination of keys to switch the language.

Answer (score 0):

I already wrote in [the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/972918/66509) to duplicate question the following:

> It is known ugly bug - see launchpad [bug 1245473](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1245473).
>
> I'm writing this from Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with MATE DE. It does not have this problem.
> I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> layout switcher for English and Russian languages.
> I see no interference here.
>
> But MATE on Ubuntu 17.10 has this problem - see other [launchpad bug 1720364](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1720364).
>
> My complete position is written [in comment 528 for bug 1218322 at launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322/comments/528).

I tried to start [discussion in ubuntu-devel-mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2017-May/017419.html) without positive results.
I'll continue to use and recommend Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with MATE DE wherever it is possible.

I wrote message to attract attention and discussion on the new [community.ubuntu.com site](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/keyboard-layout-switching-problems-and-poll/2876).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and effort to change it by reporting the bug! I also use Russian. I had to give up CTRL + SHIFT combination :( Even I get use to it and switch to ALT + SHIFT. In order to work in various applications.